# IOS Unit converter Need help with double picker and using two NSMutible arrays

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am making an iOS unit converter and need help making a double picker the proper way. I know how two return 2 in the number of components section. Ill post a sample of my code below, all help and criticism is great fully appreciated.

```
           [theArray1 addObject:@"Feet-Inch"];
           [theArray1 addObject:@"Feet-Milimeter"];
           [theArray1 addObject:@"Feet-Centimeter"];
           [theArray1 addObject:@"Feet-Meter"];
           [theArray1 addObject:@"Inch-Milimeter"];
           [theArray1 addObject:@"Inch-Centimeter"];
           [theArray1 addObject:@"Inch-Meter"];


           [thePicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];



           }

      -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
       return 1 ;

          }
      -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)
      pickerViewnumberOfRowsInComponent:
     (NSInteger)component{  return [theArray1 count];

          }





            -(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)
           pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)
        component{
         return [theArray1 objectAtIndex:row];

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just switch between two arrays with the help of the component parameter.

like this:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {  
    if (component == 0) {
        return [array1 count];
    }
    else if (component == 1) {
        return [array2 count];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

rewrite your other delegate methods with the same pattern.

Comment: seriously i live for this website, idk anything I'm having trouble with you guys always help!!!! All of you are very smart thanks again!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: could you possibly be a bit more specific as delegate methods go. i tried that and it works only for the first row even when i name them consecutively i.e. ....... if (component == 2){....} else if (component == 3){....} return 0; }